# Google Earth Engine Python API: map function

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-earth-engine

Does the use of the Earth Engine map function, e.g. map a list of bands over an Image Collection, in the Earth Engine Python API have access to the Python map function? Is there a possibility of Python mixing up between the two types?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to show code examples of what you're talking about and try to limit your question to a single topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the use of the Earth Engine map function, e.g. map a list of bands over an Image Collection, in the Earth Engine Python API have access to the Python map function?

You can certainly use one inside the other if you want. But this is subject to the usual Earth Engine programming considerations of [client vs. server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) — you can't, for example, get a Python `list` out of a feature's properties when you're mapping over a feature collection, so writing `map(function, feature.get('p'))` will never work.

But if you already have a client-side `list` (or other sequence) then there's nothing stopping you from using Python `map` on *that* inside a mapped function.

> Is there a possibility of Python mixing up between the two types?

No. One is a global builtin and the other is a method of the `ee.List` type. It is always unambiguous, to Python, which one you are using; they just happen to be spelled the same; `x.map` and `map` are entirely separate.